# Function with $f \circ f \circ f=f$

Tags: functions

What are the functions with $f \circ f \circ f=f$ defined from a set $E$ to itself?

I can prove that such a function is onto iff it is one to one. So suppose also that $f$ is bijective.

If $E=\mathbb{R}$ we have as solutions $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=-x$ or functions defined piecewise with those functions.

Can we describe all solutions for $E=\mathbb{R}$? For $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>0$ integer?

Comment: Since $f$ is assumed to be bijective, we can compose both sides of your equality with $f^{-1}$ and so obtain $(f\circ f)(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any further restrictions there is a huge array of solutions, particularly for infinite sets $E$. For instance, if you write $E$ is a disjoint union of doubletons $E=\bigcup D_i$, with $D_i=\{a_,b_i\}$, then defining $f:E\to E$ by $f(a_i)=b_i$ and $f(b_i)=a_i$, clearly solves $f\circ f \circ f=f$. This shows how random such functions can be as the decomposition of E into doubletons can be quite horrible.

In $R^n$, any reflection about a line solves the equation. Similarly, any rotation by $\pi$ radians about a point solves the equation. The identity function of course also solves the equation. The inversion $z\mapsto 1/z$ is also a solution.

All of these examples are actually ones where $f=f^-1$. Any such function will, of course, also solves your equation. So, if you include the condition that $f$ is bijective, then $f^{-1}$ exists, and then applying it to the equation yields $f\circ f = id$, in other words $f$ is an involution. In short, under the assumption of bijectivity, solutions to $f\circ f\circ f=f$ are the same as solutions to $f\circ f = id$.

Other solutions are obtained by writing $E$ as a disjoint union of doubletons and/or singletons, with $f$ defined similarly.

Comment: You forgot the non-bijective functions. $f\equiv c$ for any constant $c$, for example. Or functions $f$ such that there is some disjoint union $E = \bigcup A_i$ such that $f(A_i) = a_i \in A_i \quad\forall i$

Comment: OP stated $f$ to be bijective.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the OP, but to me it looked like that supposition was not part of the question but part of his thoughts on the problem. Evident of that is that a "function defined piecewise by [$x$ or $-x$]" will not be bijective in general.

Comment: Ah, I see. Hopefully OP can clarify.

Comment: In that case the actual condition is $f\circ f|_{f(E)} \equiv \mathrm{id}$, so it's slightly weaker, but not by much. You can then use your construction for $f(E)$ instead of $E$ and map $E\setminus f(E)$ arbitrarily into $f(E)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's partition $\mathbb{R}$ into parts of size one or two, e.g. 
$$\mathbb{R}=\{1,-1\}\cup \{3,\pi\}\cup \{7\}\cup \cdots$$
On the parts of size two, $f$ will send one element to the other.  On the parts of size one, $f$ will fix that element.

$f(x)=x$ corresponds to the partition where each part is of size $1$.  $f(x)=-x$ corresponds to the partition where each nonzero element is in a part with its negative, and $0$ is in a part of size $1$.

Since $f=f^{-1}$, it is easy to see that any bijective $f$ induces such a partition.

Answer (score 1):

There are *many*. For instance, just try any permutation of two integers, that "flips" them.

For $\mathbb{R}^2$ you have rotations, etc.

Off the top of my head I'm not sure the constraints you need for this to be interesting (continuous for one).

Comment: I'm pretty sure $f\circ f \circ f = 1$, not f. $f^4=f$ though

Comment: Your permutation example is actually an example of $(f\circ f\circ f)(x)=x$ rather than $(f\circ f\circ f)(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: @Semiclassical yeah, confused with identity. fixed.